# Ошибка при переборе объекта - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: jquery

При переборе объекта возникает ошибка:

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

var fields = {
    ip: {title: "IP", width: "6%"}
    browser: {title: "Browser", width: "9%"}
}

var visibleRowsNames = [], visibleRows = [];
$.each($('thead .column-header-text:visible'), function (i, elem) {
    visibleRowsNames.push($(elem).text());
});

$.each(fields, function (i, field) {
    if ($.inArray(field.title, visibleRowsNames) !== -1) {
        visibleRows.push(i);
    }
});
```

Что бы не было ошибки выполняю проверку:

```
if (field !== undefined && field !== null && $.inArray(field.title, visibleRowsNames) !== -1)
```

Ошибки нет и всё хорошо.
Данное решение не красивое.
Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли альтернатива ?
Спасибо.

Comment: Нет такой ошибки. Есть только `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` потому что нет запятой в объекте. А приведенных вами ошибок - нет. Вы либо не всё показали, либо одно из двух))

Comment: Естественно я показал не весь код, это только его часть с проблемой которую я знаю как решить.
Но решение мне не нравится.

Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
Происходит из-за того что при переборе объекта нет текущего элемента в наборе, он равен то undefined то null.
В конечном итоге все работает хорошо, если в условиях указывать:
if (field !== undefined && field !== null && $.inArray(field.title, visibleRowsNames) !== -1)

Собственно от сюда и вопрос, нет какого либо более элегантного метода для обхода ?

Comment: "Естественно я показал не весь код, это только его часть с проблемой которую я знаю как решить" --- Так а зачем вы показываете здесь один код, а решаете другую проблему? Смысл как раз в том, чтобы вы предоставили [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) для **текущей проблемы**, а не просто, чтоб в вопросе что-то было. В текущем его состоянии - он не имеет смысла и помочь никто не сможет **АДЕКВАТНО**, пока нет корректного кода с тем, что вы делаете. В ином случае ответ один будет - ваши костыли прекрасны!))

Comment: Воспроизвести не получится, т.к. огромная библиотека с обширным динамическим контентом, который подгружаясь генерирует DOM.

Comment: Я четко обрисовал ситуация, при переборе объекта индекс есть, значение отсутствует, вопрос заключался в том возможно ли стандартными методами JQUERY избавится от ошибки. Тут и кода не нужно приводить, т.к. всё четко сформулировано и предельно понятно. Ваш сарказм мне не понятен. Не чего сказать, проходим мимо, лесом. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну чётко, так чётко. Вот вам и пачка чётких ответов смотрю написано....в соответствии с вашей чёткой проблемой